# What is inside the qChecksum of Qt?

Tags: c#, qt

I'm currently working on a project where I have to decrypt/crypt some string values. I'm working with C# in visual studio 2019, and the objective is to decrypt data to interact with them in an application WPF, and then re-crypt the data after use.

The crypt/decrypt algorithm used is the SimpleCrypt from Qt C++, and I have to transcript that one into C#.

For the context, the data are first crypted once, then I take them from an XML file, decrypt them for use, then crypt them back for the final place to use the data.

I already found how to decrypt the data (transcripted in C#), but when I have to crypt it back, I need to use something similar to the qChecksum. Problem, I don't understand how this function work.

```
QByteArray ba = plaintext;             //plaintext = "2"
QByteArray integrityProtection;
QDataStream s(&integrityProtection, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   s << qChecksum(ba.constData(), ba.length());
```

My data is equal to a string `"2"` and I suppose to find an integrity protection equal to `"âé"`.
After much research, I didn't find what was the exact algorithm used for this function...

Maybe someone has the answer ?

Comment: Did you try looking at the source code for `qChecksum`?

Comment: Actually, just looking at [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qChecksum) tells you what's going on. It's a CRC-16, following ISO 3309. The internet claims that [this](https://github.com/satyendrakumarsingh/ISO-IEC-3309-compliant-16-bit-CRC-in-C-Language/blob/master/iso_iec_3309_crc.c) is a valid C implementation, which should be easy to port

Comment: @canton7 Yes, i went inside the deepest code i could and the final page was the qChecksum definition on qt website in one side, and the prototype inside qbytearray.h in the other side, but nothing on how this works...

Comment: @canton7 thanks for the links, i'll study that !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Qt Forum, I finally found the answer. If you are reading this, guy who's searching the qChecksum, it's corresponding to the CRC16CCITT/X.25 algortithm.

Thanks and good luck !